# Importing undefined which does not have a ɵmod property at node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:24155:19 [ProxyZone] at Array.forEach

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest

After an upgrade to Angular 13, my Jest unit tests are failing and i cannot understand why and how to fix them. I´ve searched for a while now and i have found some info for similar cases. It seems the reason for such fails is a change in Angular 13 which makes Jest somewhat incompatible, even though I´m using the latest version of Jest (27.4).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzlrq.png)

Comment: @here - Can someone please help me fix this issue?

Comment: Is anybody active here?